# Making the "setup.py" file

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I've made a new library for my project.now i decided to release it so all people can use it.

As far as i know,i should include a `setup.py` file with it so it can be installed.

After searching the web and using examples in the internet,i made this file,but instead of making a directory in `C:/python34/Lib/site-packages/ash/cocapi/cocapi.py` , it makes an .egg file:`C:\Python34\Lib\site-packagesash.cocapi-1.0-py3.4.egg` file.

I want it to make a directory like all other libraries.
here is the code i am using in `setup.py`.

What am i doing wrong in it?!

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='ash.cocapi',
      version='1.0',
      description='Unofficial Clash of Clans API Library',
      author='Ali Shadanpour',
      author_email='ash.nfu@gmail.com',
      url='https://github.com/madl-ash/Ash.CoCAPI/',
      packages=['ash', 'ash.cocapi'],
      platforms=['Linux', 'FreeBSD', 'BSD', 'Unix', 'Mac', 'OS X', 'Windows'],
     )
```

It is a view of my files:

```
/
setup.py
/ash
    __init__.py
    /cocapi
        __init__.py
        cocapi.py
```

This is the command i have tried `python setup.py install`

Comment: what command are you running on that setup.py file?

Comment: `python setup.py install`

Comment: Why do you care if your package is installed as a directory or as an egg?

Comment: there are several reason,first,it shouldn't be like this,second,i have 2 more libraries to add,i want all of them to be in one directory:`ash`,and lastly,im going to edit it in order to make new versions so if it install as a directory,it would help me to save time.also,if it install as egg,some clients may think that is it corrupted.